# Google onEdit Script for multiple columns drop downs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some script that allows me to select multiple items from a drop down in google sheets. I have the below script which works fine for column L(12) but I want this to also work on column M(13) and N(14). I have tried || (as in OR) which then makes all the drop downs in the sheet also allow multiple selections which I don't want. Can anyone help me with this?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();if(activeCell.getColumn() == 12 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Client information"){
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
if(oldValue.indexOf(newValue) <0) {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+','+newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
}
}
}
}
}
function myFunction() {
  
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for multiple dependent dropdowns or are the all independent of each other.

Comment: Hi Cooper, i was looking for them to be independent of each other. NaziA has given me the fix for this but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that those columns should be within the range of the statement as what dared provided as an answer. `column` should be within 12 and 14 inclusively.

Additionally, I have made some modifications to make use of the event object instead of `SpreadsheetApp` and improved your `if-else` block.

#### Code Modifications:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Spreadsheet object can be retrieved from event via e.source
  var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  // Range object can be retrieved from event via e.range
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  if (sheetName == "Client information" && column >= 12 && column <= 14 && e.value) {
    var newValue = e.value;
    var oldValue = e.oldValue;
    // first if statement is the default behavior, no need to include
    // the else statement is now combined on the outer if statement
    if (!e.oldValue)
      range.setValue(newValue);
    else {
      if (oldValue.indexOf(newValue) < 0) 
        range.setValue(oldValue + ',' + newValue);
      else
        range.setValue(oldValue);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: hi @MoragAtkinson, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Hi this is working but I have another script running that it is interfering with.

Comment: Hi @MoragAtkinson, it seems that the new issue should be posted as another question since it deviates from the main issue in this post. Feel free to accept any answer here if it helped you and your other issue will be addressed in another post.

Comment: Hi @MoragAtkinson, if that's the case, can you include the other script in the post so that we can understand a bit more why it doesn't work now?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tip. I will do that,

Comment: @MoragAtkinson, if you can also share a sample sheet I can see where the script is bound, that would be great.

Comment: Hi Sorry it's taken a while to respond to you. Thank you for taking the time to look at this .https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MXLOvM1Wz2ZfZv-RKjdRw1TVzj16rELCIGi9-zgtMHw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @MoragAtkinson, You are having 2 `onEdit` functions on the same sheet. You need to simplify it and combine into a single function. And for that, post another question. Your conditions on both functions are conflicting. simply combining into 1 function won't work.

Comment: Hi @NaziA thanks for your help. I will post another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {

    // cache the column number
    let col = e.range.getColumn()

    if ( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Client information" &&
         col > 11 && col < 15) {

      // This block will run if any of the columns L, M or N are edited

      // If you need different behaviour depending on which column was edited test the column number
      // Column L
      if (col === 11) {
        // This block will run if column L is edited
      }
    }

    // Without seeing the type of data you are working with I'm unclear on what
    // your old and new values represent.
}
```

Comment: I can share the google doc I am working on if that would help?